# Can you display different components on different zoom levels with react-google-maps and have smooth transitions when zooming?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I am using React and react-google-maps, and I want to display different components at different zoom levels. These components are like different layers of data.
I was thinking of making the code something like this:

```
<GoogleMap
    ref={this.ref}
    onZoomChanged={this.zoomHandler}
>
   { this.state.showComponent1 && <Component1 /> }
   { this.state.showComponent2 && <Component2 /> }
</GoogleMap>
```

The way I did this was that my zoomHandler function will check the map's zoom level, then once it passes a certain point, I want to switch which component is being viewed.

```
zoomHandler() {
    ...
    // If zoom level is >= 13, then change component view
    const zoom = this.ref.current.getZoom();
    const bool1 = zoom >= 13;
    if (this.state.showComponent1 !== bool1) {
        this.setState({ showComponent1: bool1, showComponent2: !bool1 });
    }

    ...
}
```

The problem is that I have to call setState, which will rerender the entire map. Is there a way for me to have a smooth transition where the old component will fade out and the new component will come in? These components are fairly static, so not a lot of updates. Or is there a different map library that would make this easy?
This is the library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-maps

Answer (score 1):

I use UseState in Hooks in this [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hooks-onzoomchange-b3eemr) which shows a different component when a certain zoom level is reached. In this code, I used the Circle and Polygon component of the react-google-maps library. When the zoom level reached 13 or above it will render to Polygon Component however zoom level below 13 will show a Circle Component. This will not re-render the Map only the Circle and Polygon Component.

This is where I declare my state variables:

```
 const [center, setCenter] = useState({ lat: 40.7290705, lng: -74.0105223 });
  const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(11);
  const [bool1, setBool1] = useState(null);
  const refMap = useRef(null);
```

This is my handleZoomChanged function where I get the current value of my Zoom level and setting the bool1 variable to either true or false depending on my Zoom Level:

```
 const handleZoomChanged = () => {
    const newZoom = refMap.current.getZoom(); //get map Zoom
    setZoom(newZoom);
    console.log("this is new zoom: " + { zoom }.zoom);

    if (newZoom >= 13) {
      setBool1(true);
    } else {
      setBool1(false);
    }
  };
```

Inside the return I use the code below to render either the Polygon or Circle Components depending on my bool1 value:

```
 {bool1 ? (
        <Polygon.../>
      ) : (
        <Circle..../>
      )
 }
```

*Note: Please change the value of YOUR_API_KEY in the index.js file for the code to run.*